# To read fileName as commandLine argument and perform file Operation "open" in c++98 Linux

Tags: c++, file, dynamic, command-line-arguments

I am reading abc.cpp file which is placed under /home/documents/abc.cpp. To open file I am performing file operation open("**t.open("/home/documents/abc.cpp**"). where i am able to perform open operation on file.

I want to try to read file name using command line argument. so what i am trying here is in command line

./a.out **abc.cpp** , passing argv[1] as file name and concatenate string path + argv[1], when i compile the code i will thrown with compilation errors, how to solve this issue please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>
#include<string.h>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>

using namespace std; 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                ifstream t;
                string path = "/home/documents/";
                string file = path + argv[1];
                t.open(file);
                //t.open("/home/documents/abc.cpp");
                string buffer;
                string line;
                while(t)
                {
                        getline(t, line);
                        // ... Append line to buffer and go on
                        buffer += line;
                        buffer += "\n";
                }
                t.close();
return 0;
}
```

compilation error

```
g++ cmdLine.cpp
cmdLine.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
cmdLine.cpp:13:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)’
                     t.open(file);
                                ^
cmdLine.cpp:13:32: note: candidate is:
In file included from cmdLine.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:538:7: note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:538:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
```

Comment: Could you also share the compilation errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.open(file.c_str());` will solve your problem. Until C++11 the only function declaration was

```
void open( const char *filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

The error message informs you very clearly: no known conversion from ‘std::string’ to ‘const char*’.